# Connecting Quickblox to app using cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, quickblox

I have tried everything I can to get my swift app connected to Quickblox.

I'm using Cocoa pods witht he following podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.2'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'chat-ios' do

pod 'QuickBlox'

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do $
configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK$
end
end

end
```

I've then added a bridging header which I borrowed from the Quickblox swift example but it fails to work.

I get a host of errors as shown in the Quickblox.h file:

[image: error in xcode]

I also get errors in the bridging file along the lines of:

Could not build module Quickblox.h
QMServices.h file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Quickblox, but i made successful way through cocoa pods. Using [this guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework):

started [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started), and just followed the movie.

if after

```
"sudo gem install cocoapods"
```

you get an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj
```

try

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

after setting up pods follow this [swift-connection-guide](https://quickblox.com/blog/building-ios-apps-with-quickblox-and-swift/)

and after don't forget to continue [first link](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework) , at the bottom of it there are some notes about setting up your app with Quickblox security keys.

note, that

```
[QBApplication sharedApplication].applicationId = your_app_id;;
[QBConnection registerServiceKey:@"your_app_service_key"];;
[QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"your_app_authorization_secret"];;
//Go to admin.quickblox.com/account and copy Account Key: 
[QBSettings setAccountKey:accountKey];
```

is Obj-C and some methods are deprecated. Now use:

```
    QBSettings.setApplicationID(XXXXX)    // integer, no ""
    QBSettings.setAuthKey("XXXXXXXXX")    // Your
    QBSettings.setAuthSecret("XXXXXXXXX") // keys
    QBSettings.setAccountKey("XXXXXXXXX") // here
```

In AppDelegate don't forget :

```
import Quickblox
```

if Xcode does not bark at you (that Quickblox is Obj-c) - probably you win.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. Also please note that settings should be set with 
[QBSettings setApplicationID:your_app_id;
[QBSettings setAuthKey:@"your_app_service_key"];
[QBSettings setAuthSecret:@"your_app_authorization_secret"]; and unfortunately we don't have Quickblox built as a dynamic framework. Mainly because we still need to support iOS 7.
So, removing option 'use_frameworks!' from your Podfile will fix described issue.

We will try to find out more appropriate solution in nearest future.

Comment: Btw, SevenDays, is it possible to contact you or someone from Quickblox team? I'm not going to ask code questions, but want to initiate a discussion about documentation.

Comment: You can ask your questions by the link https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: @SevenDays - Now I'm confused, I just followed Mikhail's post and I have use_frameworks in and it seems to work ok?

Comment: Also thanks a lot @MikhailKrasnoselskiy seems to work following your guide!